# AKS cannot impersonate AAD user

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, azure-aks

**Env**: AKS,

**k8s version**: 1.21.2

Enabled AKS managed AAD in cluster, and I have admin permission

When I run

```
kubectl auth can-i get pods -n dev
```

it returns **yes**, which means I have permission

But when I try to impersonate myself or a teammate

```
kubectl auth can-i get pods -n dev --as myname@mydomain.com
```

It returns

```
no - Azure does not have opinion for this non AAD user. 
If you are an AAD user, please set Extra:oid parameter for impersonated user in the kubeconfig
```

I can't see a reason why user impersonation not work